# Assign task to user in viewflow

Tags: django, django-viewflow

I am using django-viewflow in one of my application. I don't want to assign user to a task as soon as it is being created using Assign(). 
When a user logs in, I want to check if there are any unassigned task if so, fetch one and assign to a user. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds unpractical, What if 2 users would log in simultaneously? But generally, you can take an idea from viewflow assign view code https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/viewflow/flow/views/task.py#L174